# Error in model frame with variable length in R

Tags: r, csv

Today is my first day using R and I am having a problem which I could not find a solution to. 
I want to use decision tree on a data and I'm using this command:

```
library(tree)
options("na.action")
setwd('C:/Users/aanam/Documents/Amrita_internship') pschool =
read.csv('predict_school_new.csv', header = TRUE)

stree = pschool[,c(2,4,6,8,10)]
train = sample(1:nrow(stree),nrow(stree)/2)
test = -train

training_data = stree[train,]
testing_data = stree[test,] 
campus = stree[,1]

testing_campus = campus[test]
tree_model = tree(campus~.,data = training_data, na.action = "na.exclude")
```

The error that I'm getting is -

```
tree_model = tree(campus~.,data = training_data, na.action = "na.exclude")
# Error in model.frame.default(formula = campus ~ ., data = training_data,  : 
#   variable lengths differ (found for 'campus_id')
```

I looked at the NA fields and there is none

```
sum(is.na(stree))
# [1] 0
```

and I also checked the lengths of the individual columns, they are all same.

```
length(stree[1,])
# [1] 5
length(stree[,1])
# [1] 2412147
length(stree[,2])
# [1] 2412147
length(stree[,3])
# [1] 2412147
length(stree[,4])
# [1] 2412147
length(stree[,5])
# [1] 2412147
```

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

Comment: I am surprised `testing_data = stree[test,]` works, as `test` is the negative of `train`: `test = -train`

Comment: @Pascal but `train` contains row indexes (ie `c(1,5,8,12)`) and when you subset by negative indexes, you just remove those values from the vector/list. So it shouldn't be too surprising (ie `(1:10*2)[-c(3,5,7)]`

Comment: @MrFlick I didn't know that as I never subset that way. But it makes sense now.

Comment: Actually I just saw a tutorial and tried to follow the steps. So it looked like the rows not used for training set is used for testing when you do test =-train

Answer (score 4):

In your model you have

```
 tree(campus~., data = training_data, ...
```

And you appear to be blending two different variable contexts there. The `campus` part appears to come from the `campus` variable you defined above that's equal to `stree[,1]`. However, the `.` pulls all of it's values from the data parameter, in this case `training_data`. This is shorter than `stree` because you've only selected a siubset of the rows. The lengths you should be comparing are

```
length(campus)
#and
nrow(training_data)
```

I can't tell if your input data has proper headers or not. If so, it's always best to use the column names from the data.frame in the formula when fitting a model using the formula (`~`) syntax. It's not a good idea to mix variables inside and outside the data.frame. You are setting `header=T` so it would be interesting to see

```
names(stree)
```

And then use those in your formula. If the first column is in fact called "campus_id" as the error message suggests, then just use

```
 tree(campus_id ~., data = training_data, ...
```

and don't create the separate `campus` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare these two :

```
length(campus)

nrow(training_data)
```

They should match since the campus should come from training data!

The problem is , here your training data is divided into half and your are choosing campus from main data set which has double number of rows as training data. R is confused which campus to use and it uses the main data set. so here use `$` and have it refer to your training data. I hope this helps.